# The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The app must ask for a basic read permission like email at install time

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to login with facebook. I'm getting the following error:

> The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The app
>   must ask for a basic read permission  like email at install time

It means that I need first only require read informations...and is what I'm doing.
There's my code:

```
 _btnLogin.readPermissions = @[@"user_about_me"];
 _btnLogin.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error changing the permissions to:

```
 _btnLogin.readPermissions = @[@"email", @"user_friends"];
```

but before work